# C# Application exits without apparent cause

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a very repeatable situation where if I click a button in my C# WinForms app, the app always shuts down unexpectedly, but also gracefully.  By gracefully I mean that I put a breakpoint in the app_FormClosing event, and it breaks there.  The problem is, I cannot tell what caused the app to close!  I put breaks on every Environment.Exit, Application.Exit, this.Close I could find, and none of them are hit in the debugger.  The app is not supposed to close at this time, but it very repeatably and cleanly does so.

In VS2010 I enabled breaking at all exception types, and no exceptions are occurring.

How can I figure out what is causing my app to close?  Is there a way to trace it?

EDIT: During the FormClosing event, the e.CloseReason is set to CloseReason.None.  I do not see how or why this can occur.

Comment: Any chance you set a `DialogResult` value to the button in question?

Comment: Try breaking on handled exceptions as well.

Comment: Make sure you have the Win32 set to break on exceptions as well.

Comment: I have the compiler set to break on all exception types.  None are occurring.

Answer (score 3):

Hook into the following events before the main form is created:

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
    Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
```

Send the output to a MessageBox, file or elsewhere to see if you're getting any unknown exceptions.

Comment: Yikes. Sorry. Do you interact with any COM components? Or do P/Invoke Interop in any fashion?

Comment: I do have to interact with non-.NET code (C code), but I have all the source and normally see exceptions float up from that stuff if something bad happens.

Comment: It is certainly possible if something corrupts a stack in non-managed code that your process could behave in undefined ways.